# Properties with 'enumerable' flag are listed in for/in loop?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and learning now. I have the below query regarding the for/in loop and the 'enumerable' attribute of javascript object property.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
var base = {x:1, y:2, z:3}
var derived = Object.create(base)
derived["a"]=4
for(var prp in derived) { console.log(prp, derived.propertyIsEnumerable(prp)) }
```

For the above code the output is:

> a true
>   x false
>   y false
>   z false

As I understand that the inherited properties are not enumerable, and my question is why they are listed in for/in loop .

As per my understanding the output should be :

> a true.

Please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: @IazertyuiopI: What's wrong with using an object literal to create a prototype?

Comment: @Bergi My bad - seemingly nothing, but I did not know about this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable):

> Every object has a propertyIsEnumerable method. This method can determine whether the specified property in an object can be enumerated by a for...in loop, **with the exception of properties inherited through the prototype chain**.

`for..in` will iterate through any of the object's enumerable properties, but `propertyIsEnumerable` will only be `true` for the object's "own" enumerable properties, and `false` for inherited ones.

Comment: See also this table: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties#Detection_Table (Inherited Enumerable)

Comment: you mean , this method always return 'false' for the properties that are inherited?
Also if a property is inherited, will it have the 'enumerable' attribute by default or if the attribute is also inherited along with property?

Comment: Yes. Try the same loop over `base`, and you will see that the properties are enumerable. That's why they appear in the for-in-loop over the `derived` object. The property attributes are inherited so to say, yes.

Comment: @Pradeep_Evol Yes, it will always return `false` for inherited properties. And inherited properties will be enumerable or non-enumerable based on whether they are enumerable or non-enumerable in the source object. See: http://jsfiddle.net/W6MkM/